# configure css auto completion in phpstorm

Tags: css, autocomplete, phpstorm

Using PHPStorm 3.0:

Is there a way to tame auto-completion in css files?
I've disabled everything in "Preferences > Editor > Code Completion", yet I still observe the following behavior:

Say I'd try to type

```
.list {

}
```

When typeing ".list" and pressing the space key to add a { bracket, PHPStorm automatically expands .list to

```
.list-style-type:

;
```

This happens with almost every other word that also occurs as a css property **even in comments**
Any ideas on how to stop this without altering PHP/JS auto complete behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you set Space shortcut for live template expanding (Settings | Live templates). If so, this behaviour is by design.

Comment: Better check below answer, because if you disable live templates you can't use them. Just disabling `insert selected variant by typing dot, space, ect.` is much better as you can still use completion by hitting tab or enter.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Editor > General > Code Completion`.
Uncheck `Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, ect.`

After doing this, your example of `.list {` will no longer insert `.list-style-type:` when pressing `space` before the `{`.

Comment: That saved me a lot of pain, not only with auto-completion in CSS scope, but also in SQL and other scopes.