# CSS completion in PHPStorm not working

Tags: css, autocomplete, phpstorm

I am working 50/50 from office desktop pc and home laptop. Both have installed PHPStorm from jetbrains, both same version, same license, 99% same project settings, same OS (win 8.1).

Problem is that in my office I get perfect autocompletion, while at my laptop autocompletion doesn't work most of the time and when it does, its super slow.

I tried restarting, clearing cache etc. Nothing helped. PHP and JS autocompletion is in general very slow but works, CSS and HTML autocompletion doesnt work at all

I was thinking to maybe delete the .idea folder to completely reset the project?

Any ideas?

Comment: @Siguza Sorry, not related, and I updated question

Comment: Sorry for stating the obvious but... All decent Java-powered IDEs available today require a super-computer with tons of memory and lightning fast disk access. Is that the case in your laptop?

Comment: My laptop has better specs than the one at office, even though it feels slower, but the main problem isnt really that the autocomplete is slow, but that it doesnt show up at all

Comment: Do you work on the same project on desktop pc and home laptop? I can suggest creating a support ticket, providing steps to recreate and logs

Comment: Maybe this (quite old) question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243458/configure-css-auto-completion-in-phpstorm about "Settings / Live templates"

Comment: @bish I dont have a problem with IDE auto-completing something, quite the opposite..

Comment: @lena Yes I work on the same project, but the .idea folder is not shared. Basically code base is on git but project settings are not. Since I dont know at all what the problem is, its quite hard to create support ticket and explain how to reproduce this.

Comment: Im at the office today so gonna export phpstorm settings and copy .idea foder and try to rewrite it at home and see what happens...

Comment: Just to update, Copying .idea folder over from my office help and it all works fine now. Just a note, deleting .idea folder and letting phpstorm to re-build it didnt help. I had to copy over the one from other pc. When I have time I will compare the two directories and hopefully narrow down what was the problem